# trying to move the top search of datatables along with scrollbar of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to move the div of search of datatables to go along with scrollbar where the datatables are loading with an properly of overflow: auto;

here is my code but it is not moving along

```
$('#datatables_wrapper').scroll(function() { 
        $('#datatables_filter').animate({right:$(this).scrollRight()});
    });
```

i tried in console, it gives no error, but it does move element from its position

Comment: Instead use [scrollX](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html) option

Comment: It would be good if you could make this question clearer, with images more context, etc.

Comment: Please add workable code or demo to work on!!